# Show Inequality Below

Tags: inequality

Let m and n be positive integers.
Show that

$$\frac{(m+n)!}{(m+n)^{(m+n)}} <\frac{m!n!}{m^m n^n}$$

I know $m,n> 0$, the inequality can be rewritten as,
$$(m^m)(n^n)((m+n)!) < (m!)(n!)((m+n)^{(m+n)})$$

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: I have seen this question before, maybe a duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

take $(m+n)^{m+n}$ the coefficient of $m^mn^n$ in the equation is nothing but $(m+n)!/m!n!$ therefore when you divide it by $m^mn^n$ you will have the coefficient + some positive terms thus this will always be greater than the coefficient itself